# Trying to reboot ADSL modem via expect script

Tags: linux, telnet, expect

I'm trying to create a Linux script which can reboot my ASDL Modem.

Here is my `rebootModem.exp` file :

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set userName admin
set pass admin
set command reboot #It is modem reboot command

set timeout 20
spawn telnet 192.168.1.1
expect "Login: "
send "$userName\r"
expect "Password: "
send "$pass\r"
send "$command\r"
```

When I running that file it gets me :

```
spawn telnet 192.168.1.1
Trying 192.168.1.1...
Connected to 192.168.1.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
BCM96338 ADSL Router
Login: admin
Password: [kamix@localhost ~]$
```

It seems `send "$command\r"` doesn't work!.

What am I missing here ?

**P.S :**

`rebootModem.exp` is executable(`+x`).

Comment: Maybe you need to wait for a prompt or something before you send that `reboot`? Maybe you need a newline after the `reboot`?

Comment: First post edited. Output has changed. Take a look please

Comment: I don't understand why you think you need interact. Can you try without it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution :

[interact](http://wiki.tcl.tk/3914) must be used after reboot command :

```
#!/usr/bin/expect 

set userName admin
set pass admin
set command reboot

set timeout 20
spawn telnet 192.168.1.1
expect "Login:"
send "$userName\r"
expect "Password:"
send "$pass\r"
expect ">"
send "$command\r"
interact
```

Comment: I would suggest `expect eof` could be used instead

Comment: Can you show me an example ?

Comment: In place of `interact`, put `expect eof`